# Multiple background process not working

Tags: php, linux, centos, exec, background-process

I have a php script that run multiple php scripts in the background process on my centos.

Main script:

```
for($i=0;$i<=5;$i++){
exec("/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/l/msnd2.php {$i} > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
}
```

Background script (script is long - only top code):

```
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit', -1);
date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Lagos');
ignore_user_abort(TRUE);
ob_implicit_flush(TRUE);
set_time_limit(0);

....
?>
```

The problem here is that the background scripts does not run in the same time... it's a long running script it needs to finish the first script then go to the second then the third.

all I want here is to run the scripts in the same time.

I'm not sure if this a PHP related problem or linux.

Running on Centos:
16GB ram and 3 cores - SSD

Comment: could be something in the script blocking the others like db access

Comment: I don't think so... When i run this background proccess i can't even connect to my website .. its just KEEPS loading until the three background proccess are done. :(

Comment: well its "something" in the code you havent shown us

Comment: The rest of the code is a while that insert some rows in the database just like this below :

$sql = "select * from aquad where id between 600 and 700";
$content = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($content)){
$sql = "insert into open_g values(...........);
mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
}

Does this have something to do with my problem? please let me know...